# When to use xfs_copy, and when to use xfsdump

Tags: linux, xfs

I'm about to copy data from one XFS file system to another (smaller) XFS file system. The file systems may be unmounted while copying. I don't want to have to worry about ACLs, SELinux contexts, etc, so I'm looking at xfs_copy and xfsdump.

When should xfs_copy be used instead of xfsdump, and vice versa? Is one quicker than the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xfs_copy` should be used when doing an image of the source filesystem - ie: very similar to what `dd` would do.

`xfsdump` copies filesystem *content* rather than creating a true filesystem image. This measn `xfsdump` walk the filesystem and, iterating on each object, copies each file/dir (including their attributes).

When using `xfs_copy` vs `xfsdump`? From [`xfs_copy` man page:](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-xfs_copy/#lbAG)

> When moving filesystems from one disk to another, if the original
>   filesystem is significantly smaller than the new filesystem, and will
>   be made larger, we recommend that mkfs.xfs(8) and
>   xfsdump(8)/xfsrestore(8) be used instead of using xfs_copy and
>   xfs_growfs(8). The filesystem layout resulting from using
>   xfs_copy/xfs_growfs is almost always worse than the result of using
>   mkfs.xfs/xfsdump/xfsrestore but in the case of small filesystems, the
>   differences can have a significant performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

If source file system has been corrupt and can not repair by xfs_repair, you can use xfsdump salvage data and minimize your losses.